# Compare old and new values in datagridview cell in edit more

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How do I compare the values of the cell in the datagridview in edit mode? In other words, I would like to present a "YES NO" dialog box to the end-user and show the old value and the new value that he edited.

Answer (score 1):

In the form load I created some columns and rows,

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("test1");
            dt.Columns.Add("test2");
            dt.Columns.Add("test3");
            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Now, `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` will do the trick.

```
string tempValue = "";
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        tempValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(); // every edit start took the value and put it to tempValue.
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tempValue != dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()) // we need to compare tempValue and currentValue. If we don't, even we don't do any changes it will show dialog result.
        {   // take the current value (changed value)
            string currentValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString(); 
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("old value:" + tempValue + " new value:" + currentValue, "Confirm Change", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); //show dialog result
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) // if yes do something
            {
                // yes
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No) // if no cancel changed value set old value which is tempValue.
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = tempValue;

            }
        }

    }
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Would the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events fire before or after the CellValueChanged event?  Right now, I am capturing the values in the CellValueChanged event and updating the database.

Comment: If you have 3 event, First CellBeginEdit fires, Second CellValueChanged and after CellEndEdit. @dn_learner

Answer (score 0):

Would the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events fire before or after the CellValueChanged event? Right now, I am capturing the values in the CellValueChanged event and updating the database.

Comment: I will answer your question with comment at my answer. It is not proper way to ask new question with adding a new answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.